# Обработка исключений try except

Tags: python

Тема вопроса - обработка исключений.
Подскажите, я под каждую ситуацию сделал обработку с try и excpet. И если пользователь вводит неверное число - вылезает надпись: "Неверный ввод". Круто, работает. Но если этот ввод не удовлетворяет сразу нескольким условиям, то эта надпись пишется несколько раз. Как можно сделать так, чтобы вывелось одно сообщение и на этом программа остановилась? По типу break.
Пример:

```
class Error1(Exception):
    pass

class Error2(Exception):
    pass

class Error3(Exception):
    pass


password = input()
try:
    if len(password) < 4:
        raise Error1('error')
    else:
        print('Пароль верный')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    if password.startswith('0'):
        raise Error2('error')
    else:
        print('Пароль верный')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    if '@' in password:
        raise Error3('error')
    else:
        print('Пароль верный')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Если пароль неверный, то это выводится несколько раз. Как вывести только 1 раз результат? Т.е. ERROR или пароль верный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не очень понятно, зачем тут вообще exception, но раз хотите:

```
try:
    if len(password) < 4:
        raise Error1('error')
    elif password.startswith('0'):
        raise Error2('error')
    elif '@' in password:
        raise Error3('error')
    else:
        print('Пароль верный')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Если структуру `try`/`catch` менять нельзя и надо напечатать все возможные эксепшены, а не только один, но можно при этом хотя бы что-то в коде поменять, то можно сделать так:

```
def is_good_password(password):

    try:
        if len(password) < 4:
            raise Error1('error')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    
    try:
        if password.startswith('0'):
            raise Error2('error')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    
    try:
        if '@' in password:
            raise Error3('error')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    
    print('Пароль верный')
    return True
```

Comment: Вы написали не понятно зачем exception, а как по другому?

Comment: нет возможности написать под один try

Comment: @dima.programmist Хорошо, try/catch убирать нельзя, ок, а print можно убирать или тоже нет? Если нельзя ничего не сделать )  А если можно, то сейчас напишу пример.

Comment: можете пожалуйста написать 2 варианта: как правильнее написать если можно убрать, а также если нельзя собрать в один try/except

Comment: @dima.programmist Я написал, но всё-равно не зная толком ваш реальный код и ограничения на него, сложно сделать хорошо и правильно.

Comment: увидел, спасибо за ответ. А если собрать в 1 try/except? Как тогда будет выглядеть код?

Comment: @dima.programmist Так первый пример же. Только там одна ошибка напечатается, а не все возможные. Я не знаю как вам нужно.

Comment: но ведь всё по прежнему выводит несколько раз слово error, если пароль не удовлетворяет нескольким условиям. А ведь этого и не должно быть

Comment: А, стоп. Вам ошибка всё же одна нужна? Ок, сейчас подумаю ещё

Comment: просто если пароль уже поймал исключение, то и вывести слово erro. Всё, 1 раз error и программа завершается. А если исключение не поймано, то вывести, что пароль верный. А получается если ввести неправильный пароль, он выводит error несколько раз (в зависимости от кол-ва пойманных исключений)

Comment: Ну я сделал через функцию и `return`. Если это вся программа и вам реально нужно сразу выйти, воспользуйтесь ответом @timur и сделайте прямо выход из программы. Я просто всё пытаюсь более универсальное решение писать, а вам может такое и не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

```py
import sys

# какой-то код

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit(1)
```